# change element attribute value with query value

Tags: php, jquery

I do not know if it is possible, but I have to assign "button" "id=" value of query. like:

```
<button type="button" class="prevbutton" id="1">Previous</button>
<button type="button" class="nextbutton">Next</button>

<?php
                    $poffset = 0;
                    if ($d > '2016-01-01') { $whereday = "AND n.timestamp >= '$d 00:00:00' AND n.timestamp < '$d 23:59:59'"; $limit = ""; } else { $limit = "LIMIT $poffset,9"; }
                    $term = str_replace('-', ' ', $term);
                    if ($term !== '') { $whereaterm = "AND (n.news_title LIKE '%$term%' OR n.news_article LIKE '%$term%')"; $limit = "LIMIT 8,9"; }
                    $abfrage59 = "SELECT n.news_title,n.news_id as newsId,FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, n.timestamp, NOW())) as diff
                    FROM news n
                    WHERE n.domain_id = '2' AND n.timestamp < NOW() $whereday $whereaterm
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                    $limit";

                    $ergebnis59 = mysql_query($abfrage59);
                    while ($row59 = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis59)) {

                    $newstitleslug = $row59->news_title;
                    $newstitleslug = str_replace(' ', '-', $newstitleslug);
                    $newstitleslug = strtolower($newstitleslug);

                    ?><script>$(".prevbutton").attr("id", "$row59->newsId");</script><?php

                    echo "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4\" style=\"padding-bottom: 15px;\">
                            <div class=\"item\">
                                <img class=\"main\" src=\"http://lolcahost/images/news/$row59->news_id.png\" />
                                <div class=\"text\">
                                    <div class=\"inner\">
                                        <a href=\"http://localhost/news-article/$newstitleslug/$row59->news_id/\" style=\"color:white;\">$row59->news_title<br />
                                        <span class=\"date\">$row59->diff hours ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>";

                    }
                    ?>
```

SO I used this inside the php query, but id gets value "$row59->newsId", not the query value. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
?><script>$(".prevbutton").attr("id", "$row59->newsId");</script><?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot php tags:

```
<script>$(".prevbutton").attr("id", "<?=$row59->newsId?>");</script>
```

Comment: Shoudn't `<?=` be expressed properly as `<?php` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan both options are acceptable if I understand you correctly. `<?php echo $a;?>` `<?=$a;?>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.

Comment: @jekaby I have 1 more issue if you can answer. If I do `temp = temp - 9` it subtracts, but `temp = temp + 9` but this appends 9 in the end. Any idea?

Comment: because + operator does both -  addition and concatenation, and your temp seems to be a string. In case of '-', it knows it can only subtract, so it does the typecasting. hope that's clear.

Comment: @S.Kav it is because there strings, but not numbers. And js make concatenation. You can try add `Number()` or `parseInt()`: `temp = Number(temp) + 9;`